# Unzip .zip File without Writing to Disc from Response c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Let me preface by stating that I' somewhat new to dealing with zipping/unzipping/reading/reading files. That being said, I'm doing a PoC that will retrieve data via api and write the responses to a database. The response is a zip file and inside this zip is the json data I will be reading and writing to the database.

I'm having some trouble unzipping and reading the information. Please find the code below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(baseUrl),
                Headers =
                {
                    { "X-API-TOKEN", apiKey },
                },

            };

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               // here is where I am stuck - not sure how I would unzip and read the contents
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the HTTP GZIP or are you trying to unzip an attachment?

Comment: @jdweng it is a .zip

Comment: It is a MIME attachment which is in the body of the HTMP (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true) .  The attachment is a new line that starts with two dashes.  So you need to extract the attachment.  If you do not want to write to disk you need to unzip into a memory stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a `.zip` file, you don't need a `MemoryStream`, you just need to pass the existing stream to `ZipArchive`

```cs
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  // always keep static client

async Task GetZip()
{
    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(baseUrl))
    {
        Headers = {
            { "X-API-TOKEN", apiKey },
        },
    };
    using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    await ProcessZip(stream);
}

async Task ProcessZip(Stream zipStream)
{
    using var zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
    foreach (var file in zip.Entries)
    {
        using var entryStream = file.Open();
        await ....; // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: `entryStream` is showing `null` for BaseStream. Would you know why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `entryStream` is a `Stream` and has no `BaseStream` property. Perhaps you meant `StreamReader.BaseStream`, not sure how that's relevant? And why would you expect it to have a `BaseStream`?

Comment: sorry yeah I got a little confused here. It was not relevant. I was able to use your code and tweak a bit to get the json object from the zip file, so I'll be marking this as the solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `body` to a `byte` array and then unzip it using `MemoryStream`.

```
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
        using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
            CopyTo(gs, mso);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: It's a `.zip` file, not a gzipped file.

Comment: is `CopyTo` for an array?

Comment: @duls we initially have the `body` `String` which is converted into a `byte[]` called `bytes`. This array is used to create a `MemoryStream` object that we refer to as `mso`. `gs` is a `GZipStream`. `CopyTo` is a method where we pass our `gs` and `mso`. So, we initially have an array derived from a String, but at the stage when we call `CopyTo`, we already have stream objects.